# new intent crashes when running startActivity(intent);

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to call another activity from the main in an option menu. when I call the main activity from its own option menu it will correctly work but calling another intent will make an exception and the app will crash. I used try and catch and found that it will crash when it reaches this line:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

below is my main java file and the app manifest file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.times_list);
    TimeTrackerAdapter timeTrackerAdapter = new TimeTrackerAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.time_list_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_time_menu_item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTimeActivity.class);
        try {
        startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception e){};
        //return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class TimeTrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<TimeRecord> times = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();

    public TimeTrackerAdapter() {
        times.add(new TimeRecord("38:23", "Feeling good!"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("49:01", "Tired. Needed more caffeine"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("26:21", "I’m rocking it!"));
        times.add(new TimeRecord("29:42",
                "Lost some time on the hills, but pretty good."));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return times.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return times.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent
                    .getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TimeRecord time = times.get(index);

        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        timeTextView.setText(time.getTime());

        TextView notesTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
        notesTextView.setText(time.getNotes());

        return view;
    }
}

public class TimeRecord {
    private String time;
    private String notes;

    public TimeRecord(String time, String notes) {
        this.time = time;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}

public class AddTimeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_time);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.time_list_menu, m);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

and for the manirfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test02"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test02.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.test02.AddTimeActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
01-15 02:20:01.164: W/dalvikvm(3018): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test02/com.example.test02.MainActivity$AddTimeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.example.test02.MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MainActivity.java:44)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java??:986)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.??java:735)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:87??4)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.j??ava:166)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Comment: and what on earth is the error?

Comment: 01-15 02:20:01.164: W/dalvikvm(3018): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test02/com.example.test02.MainActivity$AddTimeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: 01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at

Comment: android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.example.test02.MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MainActivity.java:44)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at

Comment: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at

Comment: android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at

Comment: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-15 02:20:01.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3018):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

Comment: @HosseinDolatabadi Next time please don't post logcat as comments! You can just edit your question and add it to the original post. I just did that for you, cause I'm a nice guy.

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to launch `com.example.test02.MainActivity$AddTimeActivity` (which is an inner class of `MainActivity`), but in your manifest you haven't defined it that way. See answer from @Jerryl15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not putting the activities in the same file right?

If you really wanted to use the activity as an inner class in another activity you need to put this in your android manifest instead:

```
   <activity android:name="com.example.test02.MainActivity$AddTimeActivity" >
```

I DONT RECOMMEND THIS THOUGH. Split your inner classes into two different class files.

In the package/folder: `com.example.test02` you need to separate it and make two files `AddTimeActivity.class` and `MainActivity.class` and then you don't need to change anything in your manifest.

Have you tried making sure the package names match? Can you post your imports/package name in a comment to further clarify?

Comment: yes I do. as it can be seen, both classes are in the same file

Comment: Separate the files, in the same package. So you have separate files for your activities.

Comment: no, no, no, I think this is why you're getting the error. Please read my post again.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the manifest. I defined the new activity there

Comment: you know @jerryl15 the fact is I found it in a tutorial (in a book actually) and it has the same structure that's why I am lazy to separate them. but lets look at manifest

Comment: Thanks @Jerryl15 you were right. I put the new class in a new class file and now the code is working perfectly. I think the book is not the latest version to find. Tnx

Answer (score 3):

Add it into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.test02.AddTimeActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.AddTimeActivity" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you create the AddTimeActivity  class inside MainActivity class.

Note: Write multiple nested classes inside one class when not needed is not a good coding standard.

Follow some steps:

1st: Just cut AddTimeActivity from MainActivity and create a new one.

2nd: In you manifest just use it as:

```
<activity android:name=".AddTimeActivity" />
```

and check..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use explicit intent in your app, or if you want to start another activity using the following code:

```
Intent intent_name = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityName.class);

startActivity(intent_name);
```

And if your app crashes, then you should edit your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and define your activity which you want to start.

For example:

- If the activity you want to start is named as `MyActivity` and if your package name is `com.mycomp.myapp`, then you should add the definition given below:

  `<activity android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.MyActivity" />`